# MS Access Modify items in listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I am creating my own Access application with forms and I ran into a problem I can't solve. I'm fairly new with programming.

I created a form to create an order, this all works fine and inserts the partslist into the database. The problem is when I want to change this order. I load all parts into the ListBox via the following code: (made the query a bit smaller, it is just for example)

```
Forms!VerkoopWijzigen!lbOnderdelen.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
Forms!VerkoopWijzigen!lbOnderdelen.RowSource = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PartID=" & PartID & ""
```

This also works fine, but if I want to remove or add items to the ListBox it gives me an error:

[image: Error]

My form:
[image: A screen of my form FYI]

I already found on Stack Overflow that it is not possible to use `.AddItem` and `.RemoveItem` with a ListBox using a query (only value list). But I could not find an alternative way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, you can't use `.AddItem` and `.RemoveItem`.
Instead, modify the `RowSource`.

E.g. to add a constant item

```
RowSource = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PartID=" & PartID & _
            " UNION ALL SELECT 47, 'Bamboozle' FROM aDummyTableWithOneRecord"
```

or to remove some

```
RowSource = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE PartID=" & PartID & _
            " AND foo <> 'Bamboozle'"
```

Changing the `.RowSource` of a listbox/combobox will automatically requery it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot modify data in the ListBox directly, you need to modify data in your table and amend the .RowSource of the control as required.

For example, to exclude an item you can do this:

```
'Mark excluded
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE parts SET Excluded=True WHERE PartID=" & PartID
```

Then the .RowSource SQL would be like this:

```
With Forms.VerkoopWijzigen.lbOnderdelen
    .RowSourceType = "Table/Query"
    .RowSource = "SELECT * FROM parts WHERE Excluded=False AND PartID=" & PartID
End With
```